# a straight line crossing a line of text in webpage

Tags: html

In html, `<del> and </del>` are used to show " <del>and</del> ", a straight line crossing a line of text.

In [this forum](http://area51.phpbb.com/phpBB/index.php), when making a new post, how can I achieve the same effect?

Is the website still html?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Though I can't access that particular site due to firewall restrictions, I do know that it implements BBCode. BBCode supports the strikethrough tags `[s]text[/s]`, though I don't know if this particular site supports this tag.

Comment: @Tim -- It could be that the board does not support this particular tag. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) has a decent outline of common bbcode tags.

Answer (score 1):

Read the FAQ

http://area51.phpbb.com/phpBB/faq.php?sid=3a030cf950feb29e7cdee95345feda08#f3r1

Can I use HTML?
No. It is not possible to post HTML on this board and have it rendered as HTML. Most formatting which can be carried out using HTML can be applied using BBCode instead.

You have to follow the BBCode guidelines in changing fonts, like bold or underline, and **the way to do it is described in the post you are adding**. Stackoverflow does the same thing

http://area51.phpbb.com/phpBB/faq.php?sid=3a030cf950feb29e7cdee95345feda08#f3r0

What is BBCode?
BBCode is a special implementation of HTML, offering great formatting control on particular objects in a post. The use of BBCode is granted by the administrator, but it can also be disabled on a per post basis from the posting form. BBCode itself is similar in style to HTML, but tags are enclosed in square brackets [ and ] rather than < and >. For more information on BBCode see the guide which can be accessed from the posting page.

Example of Stack over flow:

If you add 4 spaces before a sentence it looks like this:

```
this code is now in a gray box
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the tag in BBCode corresponding to the delete tag in html?

Comment: That's up to the forum adminstrators to decide if that is allowable or if they have a markup detailing how to do that. The description is next to where you'd post, but if there is no description, then you are not allowed.

Comment: Btw, most forums do not allow you to inject html within a text in case what you do might mess up the formatting of the page, they MIGHT allow you basic html though, only if their html code is well formed to allow it. So by having a controlled environment, they provide a series of BBCodes for you to use if you want to style your fonts or paragraphs.